# MSMQ write taking > 1 minute

Tags: performance, msmq

We have an ongoing problem with message writes to MSMQ being very slow.  Our queue is on Windows Server 2008 SP2.  The queue is a public queue, addressed at "servername\queuename".

The code to send a message to the queue is

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(Settings.Default.DefaultDestinationQueue);
queue.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();

queue.Send(message);
```

The message that we're trying to send is simply a "PublishMessage", as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class PublishMessage {
    public int EntryId {get; set; }
}
```

We're seeing the messages actually reach the queue, but logging before and after shows that it's generally taking in excess of 1 minute for each message.

At this time, we can't see anything wrong with our queue configuration, but are not queuing experts--this is the first addition to this application.  Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit:** Our server is running SP 2 (not SP1 that I originally stated).  Running an instance directly on the machine hosting the queue is fast, any other is not.

**Note:** Crossposted this at https://serverfault.com/questions/272242/msmq-write-taking-1-minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problem turned out to be an infrastructure issue with servers not properly authenticating.  Our sysadmin finally got it straightened out by reconfiguring the server hosting the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the queue transactional or non-transactional? Try toggling this setting and see if you get the same behavior.

How much space is allocated for the queue? Try increasing the space, and/or moving its storage to a different drive (on a different physical spindle).

Are there messages in the system queues? Check the system queues for messages. Also, try purging all the messages from the system queues and re-run.

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonse--the answers:  1) The queues are not transactional, 2) The allocated space is 'unlimited'.  There doesn't appear to be any disk queuing at all, and 3) the system queues are empty.   Also, we're on SP2, not 1, my error.

Comment: "There doesn't appear to be any disk queuing at all"
The files are in the system32\msmq\storage directory.